# How to put all the product variants into one single dict in Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping this e-commerce [website](https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-SaksFifthAvenue-Site/en_US/Search-UpdateGrid?cgid=2534374306418048&start=0&sz=24&hideLess=true) and there some product which have multiple variants in colors and sizes as well as that variant availabilty and I am looking to gather all the variants into one single scrapy item field. I have write the scrapy code for that purpose but not working as I am expecting to work.

So far I have come to this:

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import json
import html


class SaksFifthAvenueSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "saks_fifth_avenue"

    # custom settings
    custom_settings = {
        "LOG_FILE": "saks_fifth_avenue.log",
        "FEEDS": {
            "saks_fifth_avenue.json": {
                "format": "json",
            }
        },
    }

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        # 'Cookie': f'dwanonymous_025df3a570c4fd81b224498a5e681c66=bc04JPZEiY1aIKcrhKsxr6Lx5L; shopPreference=women; E4X_CURRENCY=USD; visitor_id=b478a7e9-30a4-46f3-acfe-bfa9892d0f59; _abck=D672E98E5CB8524EB8241BE73778393F~0~YAAQRZ4QAit55haFAQAA0kIWSAmF5u/3SxeRwDNerzXkAs9HShjb4Yo79Um8fjaUmCo4lbdFDvT1QvMhM2xUkDDmV03th1E61QqMQioV/yvAEKOHD+NwDUQ4nuH5i1xE42UdtOfM2mfj+R21DzXHi8PJHxJxx9ybenj89bNM8Q5lOuYI2JTcevJO4AQrfzRAKY9V4/f1+nV9bXR/8p4WrWyAjT5WdhAuK0aWIgyHHxHLcoXDVesRdSfnv45Dv46AeWxpQfyjylobMC42+vkJ9tr3dZTvKxdVSoOP0yuuUdgZcus2O8vzpa8gqG8H3UBb2f6LBtgqiFwLn02TYcibn5KfyrqeAAemjLrCcjD20WjprlcoxijoDl9+005SpgR0dsRn/RwLPGZaU4gs+c/RHnOXw4FEVjn2ucaujfsRFyxJ~-1~||1-GbKrKTukCc-1500-10-1000-2||~1671955255; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1671885096023r0.8268628994966681; bfx.apiKey=54b0b7b0-c775-11ea-aaf6-db74ada4ea97; bfx.env=PROD; bfx.logLevel=ERROR; forterToken=bfa67aca80224c80a7dc18b72719b247_1671952800887_3822_UAL43_9ck; bfx.sessionId=bdfe3ab3-280c-48ec-ae94-743e26dd079b; bfx.country=US; bfx.currency=USD; bfx.language=en; bfx.isInternational=false; AMCV_5B7B123F5245ADFC0A490D45%40AdobeOrg=1585540135%7CMCIDTS%7C19351%7CMCMID%7C47481938145812507146759878347833243925%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1671960008s%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C4.4.0; utag_main=v_id:0185441e2172001ab91f40cf83660504600440090086e{_prevPage:saks.com%3Awomensapparel%3Aformalevening%3Bexp-1671957488981$_prevPageType:product%20array%3Bexp-1671957488981;} allMySizesSelected=false; mySizesUrl=/c/women-s-apparel/formal-evening?srule=featured_newest&prefn1=sizeRefinement&prefv1=undefined; allMyDesignerSelected=false; mySizessUrlNotCombined=https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/c/women-s-apparel/formal-evening?prefn1=sizeRefinement&srule=featured_newest; myDesignersUrl=/c/women-s-apparel/formal-evening?srule=featured_newest&prefn1=brand&prefv1=undefined; myDesignersDeselectUrl=/c/women-s-apparel/formal-evening?srule=featured_newest; myDesignersUrlNotCombined=https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/c/women-s-apparel/formal-evening?prefn1=brand&srule=featured_newest; mySizesDeselectUrl=/c/women-s-apparel/formal-evening?srule=featured_newest; bfx.currencyQuoteId=82057428; bfx.lcpRuleId=; ftr_ncd=6; __wid=232502153; cbt-consent-banner=CROSS-BORDER%20Consent%20Banner; bfx.isWelcomed=true; OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Sun+Dec+25+2022+12%3A20%3A08+GMT%2B0500+(Pakistan+Standard+Time)&version=202209.2.0&hosts=&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CBG12%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0004%3A1; emailsignup=welcomeemailsignupdecline@gmail.com; dwac_44e2d976c426d708b992de46eb=K2rEBkF03hAreiWC9kfuTQRTHPalErLhrQE%3D|dw-only|||USD|false|US%2FEastern|true; cqcid=bc04JPZEiY1aIKcrhKsxr6Lx5L; cquid=||; sid=K2rEBkF03hAreiWC9kfuTQRTHPalErLhrQE; __cq_dnt=0; dw_dnt=0; dwsid=ESfg3-gnJ0cPbvhiCXtWLj4eOC8MQUu2iRU3ysqMclU9VPWB-dHx1eiMXWm5mC2p7nRe2sNJlSdM0jVnXbnT-g==; akavpau_www_saks_com=1671955118~id=446b3317abc7aa11bc5bfa225f139017; ak_bmsc=19793DFAACCB6743F85F39639C1BDEFB~000000000000000000000000000000~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; bm_sz=8A2DE9230F8DC490D7B926B4B12AD700~YAAQV54QAiROigWFAQAAKD/xRxKz2M+2VWQ0KWdSNejQD4I2M1yCruuBvMgQLUGqxVOwskgAijOAfSbWJDXX4UBK9zX2vm+8xAZ3kTFv76acP9wMb4VonbI1GYQf+Cw7utDVBXDFcL6AgbCLUnwD/XruZ5gotF5eAMDfpBA9sUR/TN2aimOfNMmh7Fd68QdaU/e8lYNCTCxX/3tBo8lr8713PoqdhYO0a5I4f3JHNba64Sdy9slq+FfMlsNs5AE+WILC3Dbhcqs67XIlIc7YfFIRH1ah9NJrjHzVo9J4GTUKchSMfSp3fhC3Gks=~4404292~3420981; bm_sv=82CF71E79C72E211DA9CE40207CDF202~YAAQV54QAstPiwWFAQAA/uNFSBLdUKn2W9EhaqeIgjq5nCnKD8iMKvYmcHpqDUUZuxMB1v4FFgFbj5j3NOdEETvnBScbvsZm7IcQ7/CeOM6AnT8HCJ87bwShOK7dguMaMZNhhcd/hHB6vjrPbOBKnnWiPJb6UTmNCoeSbaUe//nCMVEiSXm2PH0dYZXzNQZ7kJXBbyNxYyjUKindQW8rsIEdEzL3AunrkNRYsOm7wDTBf0Z5x2tMNNFKJK2V36PWrRLNLYWyY1NGAgs=~1; bm_mi=4510A7E1A32F3C366BB5ACFDD7B284B9~YAAQV54QAnJOigWFAQAABU/xRxKqpCzsez2gyrzoMYKLHP3bGefr0gwZS4RmCX7WXzioq8VBE9OLV9UPJOi2QMgh9mQ3uvro0KqVcbPFjYTG7eOZUMr8wFb/1jglC308xcMbjOLBu762C0VJSGl9Tgc6S3Dqm7vrkfUSjp2Q1z/87KMnrkBJiNDDuyYvmcDM414JHBC8k/ZhElCZPGktOw2XK8nYXA62ESMNHZi+29OBSjt98UBPAj1Wefz0+4g4SH/Tf4uvryL+bgEYApoExZwd4x+zIKRYmguPh6CETdpA+iPWoa9KPWcrgAktWwXnt5mVSbUAEWDzu2KkVer0SQFFCgbr/VITvysZzXYyKSxmJvEQCUK83IzSKFlU28KS8VdBl4p0wsM972v+eYgzVXxIa8HRQkD4P9A=~1; AMCVS_5B7B123F5245ADFC0A490D45%40AdobeOrg=1; AKA_A2=A',
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
        "Sec-GPC": "1",
        # Requests doesn't support trailers
        # 'TE': 'trailers',
    }

    params = {
        "cgid": "2534374306418048",
        "start": "0",
        "sz": "24",
        "hideLess": "true",
    }

    base_url = "https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-SaksFifthAvenue-Site/en_US/Search-UpdateGrid?"

    def start_requests(self):
        cgid_list = ["2534374306418048"]
        for cgid in cgid_list:
            self.params["cgid"] = cgid
            category_url = self.base_url + urlencode(self.params)
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=category_url, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_page_items
            )

    def parse_page_items(self, response):
        item_links = set(
            [
                "https://www.saksfifthavenue.com" + u.split("?")[0]
                for u in response.css("a.thumb-link.mw-100::attr(href)").extract()
            ]
        )
        inner_load = response.css("div.show-more ::attr(data-url)").get()
        if inner_load:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=inner_load, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_page_items
            )

        for link in item_links:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=link, headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse_variant_urls
            )

    def parse_variant_urls(self, response):
        prod_id = response.css("div.container.product-detail::attr(data-pid)").get()
        colors = response.css("button::attr(data-adobelaunchproductcolor)").extract()
        sizes = response.css("li::attr(data-attr-value)").extract()
        variant_urls = []
        for color in colors:
            for size in sizes:
                variant_urls.append(
                    response.url
                    + "?dwvar_"
                    + prod_id
                    + "_color="
                    + color
                    + "&dwvar_"
                    + prod_id
                    + "_size="
                    + size
                )

        for v in variant_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=v,
                headers=self.headers,
                dont_filter=True,
                callback=self.parse_variants,
                meta={"product_url": response.url},
            )

    def parse_variants(self, response):
        prod_url = response.meta.get("product_url")
        v_dict = {}
        product_color = (
            response.css(
                "button.color-attribute.radio-group-trigger.adobelaunch__colorlink.unselectable.selected"
            )
            .css("::attr(data-adobelaunchproductcolor)")
            .get()
        )
        v_dict[product_color] = []
        final_price = response.css(
            "span.formatted_sale_price.formatted_price.js-final-sale-price.bfx-price.bfx-list-price::text"
        ).get()
        old_price = response.css(
            "span.formatted_price.bfx-price.bfx-list-price::text"
        ).get()
        for li in response.css("ul.radio-group-list.size-attribute").css(
            'li[role="radio"]'
        ):
            if li.css("::attr(disabled)"):
                v_dict[product_color].append(
                    {
                        "value": li.css("::attr(data-attr-value)").get(),
                        "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE",
                        "final_price": final_price,
                        "old_price": old_price,
                    }
                )

            else:
                v_dict[product_color].append(
                    {
                        "value": li.css("::attr(data-attr-value)").get(),
                        "status": "AVAILABLE",
                        "final_price": final_price,
                        "old_price": old_price,
                    }
                )

        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=prod_url,
            headers=self.headers,
            dont_filter=True,
            callback=self.parse_product_details,
            meta={"product_variants": v_dict},
            )

        yield v_dict

    def parse_product_details(self, response):
        item = {}
        item["product_brand"] = response.css("a.product-brand::text").get()
        item["product_name"] = response.css("h1.product-name::text").get()
        item["product_variants"] = response.meta.get("product_variants")

        yield item
```

I am using this [product_url](https://www.saksfifthavenue.com/product/line-dot-valeria-sequined-minidress-0400017592580.html) for example to show the above code output and my expected output.
Right now above code output is like this:

```
{"product_brand": "Line & Dot", "product_name": "Valeria Sequined Minidress", "product_variants": {"Pink": [{"value": "X-Small", "status": "AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}, {"value": "Small", "status": "AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}, {"value": "Medium", "status": "AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}, {"value": "Large", "status": "AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}]}},
{"product_brand": "Line & Dot", "product_name": "Valeria Sequined Minidress", "product_variants": {"Black": [{"value": "X-Small", "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}, {"value": "Small", "status": "AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}, {"value": "Medium", "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}, {"value": "Large", "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}]}}
```

And I'd like to have the output like this:

```
{"product_brand": "Line & Dot", "product_name": "Valeria Sequined Minidress", "product_variants": [{"Pink": [{"value": "X-Small", "status": "AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}, {"value": "Small", "status": "AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}, {"value": "Medium", "status": "AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}, {"value": "Large", "status": "AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}]}, {"Black": [{"value": "X-Small", "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}, {"value": "Small", "status": "AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}, {"value": "Medium", "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}, {"value": "Large", "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE", "final_price": "$168", "old_price": "$168"}]}]}
```

Can anyone please help me figure out how can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to send a request for each variant in parallel, one variant doesn't have the data of the other variants. What you need to do is send a request to one variant of the product after the other and collect the data. Once you have all the variants' data, you can yield the final item

Comment: I have came to that exact conclusion but my concern taking that approach was that it will make scraping process slower so I was wondering if there is any way around it without compromising the speed.

Comment: If there a lot of other products that have variants too. It shouldn't be much slower since it will be handling variants from other products in parallel too. You can also save a product id in the variants maybe and when all scraping is donee merge variants based on that id